# CSS Menu with second level out of position

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

this is the first time I am creating a menu alone, I'm beginner and I just need to fix this problem to make my menu work correctly. 
The second level menu is appearing out of position. 
Sorry for my english I'm using google translator. :(

Code CSS:
http://www.agenciafibonacci.com/menu.css

Image:
http://www.agenciafibonacci.com/ilustra.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of using classes, configure your css like:

```
/* Main MENU (horizontal)*/
#menu ul {}
#menu ul li {}
/* Sub Menu (vertical) */
#menu ul li ul {}
#menu ul li ul li {}
/* Sub menu of sub menu (horizontal) */
#menu ul li ul li ul {}
#menu ul li ul li ul li {}
```

Not having seen your html, I cannot understand what class belongs to what.